Aren't electron menus automatically localised?
In an electron.js application, I can define a menu like this:
const template = [
   {
      label: 'Edit',
      submenu: [
         { role: 'undo' },
         { role: 'redo' },
         { type: 'separator' },
         { role: 'cut' },
         { role: 'copy' },
         { role: 'paste' }
      ]
   },

I had assumed that if I did it like this, knowing that there are language resource files included with electron, that the application would automatically include the menus translated into the user's language.
I'm not finding this to be the case. Is it supposed to show translated versions? If not, what purpose does specifying the role without a hard-coded string?
My project is using Electron Vite, which in turn uses Electron Builder. Is it possible that I've simply got something misconfigured, or am I just out to lunch thinking this is built-in?
